# How to get data from a JSON object?

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to retrieve data from a JSON object that looks like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
[query] => stdClass Object
    (
        [results] => stdClass Object
            (
                [quote] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [foo] => bar
                            )
                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [foo] => blah
                            )
```

I created the object like so:

```
$json = curl_exec($session);
$stock_data = json_decode($json);
```

I have been reading several posts on how to do this ([This one was extremely useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263392/handling-data-in-a-php-json-object)) but I am still stuck. I know I need to iterate over the data, but I'm not exactly sure what the foreach statements would look like (ie the depth of them, so to speak). I realize that this should be relatively simple, but I can't wrap my head around it at the moment (that's what being evacuated does to you). Any help would be much appreciated!

**EDIT**: After thinking about it a while, this is what I came up with:

```
foreach( $stock_data->query->results as $quote) {
           foreach ($quote as $entry) {
                print $entry->{'foo'} ;
            }
       }
```

This will then successfully print both bar and blah

Comment: Which level do you want to iterate through? It'll fundamentally be a mix of PHP arrays and objects e.g. `echo $object->query->results->quote[0]->foo`

Comment: I wanted to iterate through each object within quote. I managed to figure it out though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$quotes = $stock_data->query->results->quote;
foreach ($quotes as $q)
{
  echo $q->foo;
}
```

Comment: Nice! I came up with my own solution but the two look to be extremely similar.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach( $stock_data->query->results as $quote) {
       foreach ($quote as $entry) {
            print $entry->{'foo'} ;
        }
   }
```