# issue with file_get_contents in json fetch

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

The following is from another question: *[Handling data in a PHP JSON Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263392/handling-data-in-a-php-json-object)*:

```
$jsonurl     = "http://search.twitter.com/trends.json";
$json        = file_get_contents($jsonurl, 0, null, null);
$json_output = json_decode($json);

foreach ($json_output->trends as $trend)
{
    echo "{$trend->name}\n";
}
```

My Question: What is the difference between those two:

```
file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null)
file_get_contents($jsonurl)
```

I checked [`file_get_contents()` PHP manual](http://php.net/file-get-contents), but still do not totally understand it, in another words, if i use this line:

```
file_get_contents($jsonurl)
```

What will happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will use default parameters (`false`, `null`, `-1`, `null`). In your case you do almost the same (`0` evaluates as `false`, the second `null` as no parameter, so `-1`).

So better use just `file_get_contents($jsonurl);`