# extracting specific data from json format

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have the following json format data :

```
{"query":{
  "count":5,"created":"2014-12-19T15:42:41Z","lang":"en-US","results":{
    "channel":[{
      "item":{
        "forecast":{"date":"19 Dec 2014","high":"61","low":"47"}
       }},{
      "item":{
        "forecast":{"date":"20 Dec 2014","high":"60","low":"48"}
       }},{
      "item":{
        "forecast":{"date":"21 Dec 2014","high":"61","low":"44"}
       }},{
      "item":{
        "forecast":{"date":"22 Dec 2014","high":"58","low":"46"}
       }},{
      "item":{
        "forecast":{"date":"23 Dec 2014","high":"58","low":"45"}
       }}]
     }
   }
}
```

How can I access specific data from this format (for example only high and low), in order to insert these data in a mySQL database for instance?

Comment: have you even googled? here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263392/handling-data-in-a-php-json-object

Comment: you don't "extract from json". you decode the json to a native data structure, and work with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your json in a variable `$str` for example, than you can access the items :

```
$json = json_decode($str);
$res = $json->{'query'}->{'results'}->{'channel'};
foreach($res as $ch) {
    echo "High:" . $ch->{'item'}->{'forecast'}->{'high'} . "<br>";
    echo "Low:" . $ch->{'item'}->{'forecast'}->{'low'} . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use json_decode to turn it into an array:

```
$array = json_decode($json_data, true);
```

Then, you can access the items, forecast, and high/low values:

```
$high = $array[1]['item']['forecast']['high'];
```

Comment: Add the second param if you want it to return an array. json_decode($data, true) otherwise its an object

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your json string is the variable $json:

```
$data = json_decode($json);
$channels = $data->query->results->channel;
foreach($channels as $channel) {
    // DO SOMETHING HERE
    die($channel["item"]["high"]);
}
```