# get json data from URL using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

here i try to fetch json data from following url

> https://www.flickr.com/services/api/render?method=flickr.places.find&api_key=xxxxx&query=$search_data&format=json&nojsoncallback=1

contain following information which i want to get according above link

```
{
    "places": {
        "place": [
            {
                "place_id": "Dm5SiT1TULMEIMYN",
                "woeid": "2295402",
                "latitude": 23.03,
                "longitude": 72.591,
                "place_url": "/India/Gujarat/Ahmedabad",
                "place_type": "locality",
                "place_type_id": 7,
                "timezone": "Asia/Kolkata",
                "_content": "Ahmedabad, Gujarat, India",
                "woe_name": "Ahmedabad"
            },
            {
                "place_id": "mz1zSK1YUrJTfvUrOA",
                "woeid": "90883450",
                "latitude": 23.027,
                "longitude": 72.57,
                "place_url": "/India/Gujarat",
                "place_type": "locality",
                "place_type_id": 7,
                "timezone": "Asia/Kolkata",
                "_content": "Ahmedabad, India",
                "woe_name": "Ahmedabad"
            }
        ],
        "query": "Ahmedabad, Gujarat, India",
        "total": 2
    },
    "stat": "ok"
}
```

but here problem is that this link return null i'm using following code of php

```
$json_array = file_get_contents("https://www.flickr.com/services/api/render?method=flickr.places.find&api_key=xxxxx&query=Ahmedabad,%20Gujarat,%20India&format=json&nojsoncallback=1");
$json_array = iconv('UTF-16', 'UTF-8', $json_array);
$json_data=json_decode($json_array,true);
print_r($json_data);
```

Comment: When I `echo $json_array` I get an HTML document.

Comment: yes that's right but i want to get json data

Comment: So either find a URL that gives you a JSON document, or parse the HTML.

Comment: I added a $ symbol to `print_r($json_data);` not sure if that was an issue in your actual code or not though.

Answer (score 2):

Your call is wrong. The correct one would be

```
https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.places.find&.....
```

Comment: I have checked too. But how it explains why json_decode doesn't decodes json? I have checked json with validator and it's correct.

Comment: @RomanLosev The OP didn't use the rest endpoint of the flicker API. He used the rendering endpoint, which syntax highlights the JSON via HTML. json_decode can not decode HTML. Thus it failed.

Comment: yes but doesn't get information how to get perticular information like i want to fetch place_id how?

Comment: See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263392/handling-data-in-a-php-json-object

Comment: You're welcome. You might want to mark this answer as correct, so it is easier for other people to find that face a similiar problem

Answer (score 2):

I found it, its because you are calling `/api/render` method of API so it will give `pretty printed` json

just use this url instead

```
//https://www.flickr.com/services/rest?method=flickr.places.find&api_key=c5336c8cc248142bbda940c1f771bfd5&query=Ahmedabad,%20Gujarat,%20India&format=json&nojsoncallback=1

$json_array = file_get_contents("https://www.flickr.com/services/rest?method=flickr.places.find&api_key=c5336c8cc248142bbda940c1f771bfd5&query=Ahmedabad,%20Gujarat,%20India&format=json&nojsoncallback=1");

$json_data=json_decode($json_array,true);
print_r($json_data);
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried a sample request from the `Flickr API`.

`https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.test.echo&format=json&foo=bar&api_key=cddc3ae537ed443aafa20cf2c30086df`

You need to add the following parameter `format=json` in your request URI. Also, the endpoint must be `/services/rest`.

Comment: yes that's fine but i can't scrap code of particular id information such as place_id how?

Comment: If you have received the JSON now (use whatever URL you were using), you could just use `json_decode($response, true)`. This will convert the respone into the `PHP array` object. Then you can iterate over all the responses.