# Facebook like count url

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

As Facebook changed their API and deprecated the old one, I need to get data (likes count, share count, comment count) about single pages.

I figured out how to get data over Facebook graph (example link):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?fields=og_object{likes.limit(0).summary(true)},share&ids=http://www.businessinsider.com/airlines-dont-disclose-carrier-fee-that-inflates-ticket-prices-2016-9
```

But now I don't know how to echo single data (likes count) in php. I tried with json, but had no sucsess:

```
$json = file_get_contents($xml);
$json_output = json_decode($json);
```

Any suggestions how to make this work?

Comment: what is the question? how to deal with json data in php? use var_dump to check out $json_output.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263392/handling-data-in-a-php-json-object

Comment: Thank you for your comment... var_dump of $json_output returns me "NULL".

Comment: you really need to start debugging...how about var_dump of $json then? and what´s in $xml?

Comment: `$xml = "https://graph.facebook.com/?fields=og_object{likes.limit(0).summary(true)},share&ids=http://www.businessinsider.com/airlines-dont-disclose-carrier-fee-that-inflates-ticket-prices-2016-9";

var_dump of $json = bool(false)`

Comment: i don´t see any access token, where is it?

Comment: btw, you should use curl, not file_get_contents.

Comment: I don't know how to use access token here... as my code is not requesting any user data?

Comment: read this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: you MUST use a token for api calls.

Comment: @luschn I just added access token and now works as a charm! Thank you for you help!

Comment: i´ve added the info as answer, it would be nice to accep it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API Explorer adds the Access Token automatically, but you have to add it manually in your URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?fields=og_object{likes.limit(0).summary(true)},share&ids=http://www.businessinsider.com/airlines-dont-disclose-carrier-fee-that-inflates-ticket-prices-2016-9&access_token=xxx
```

Result:

```
{
  "http://www.businessinsider.com/airlines-dont-disclose-carrier-fee-that-inflates-ticket-prices-2016-9": {
    "og_object": {
      "likes": {
        "data": [
        ],
        "summary": {
          "total_count": 0,
          "can_like": true,
          "has_liked": false
        }
      },
      "id": "949055545223224"
    },
    "share": {
      "comment_count": 0,
      "share_count": 346
    },
    "id": "http://www.businessinsider.com/airlines-dont-disclose-carrier-fee-that-inflates-ticket-prices-2016-9"
  }
}
```

Comment: works fine for me, this is actually the new way. are you sure you used it correctly, with the access token?

Comment: i have added the result. that is exactly what i get.

Answer (score 0):

The results of json_decode() are Objects. 
So you can easily browse through like this:

```
<?php    

$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/?fields=og_object{likes.limit(0).summary(true)},share&ids=http://www.businessinsider.com/airlines-dont-disclose-carrier-fee-that-inflates-ticket-prices-2016-9';

$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json_output = json_decode($json);
foreach( $json_output as $site=>$data ){
    echo $site."\n";
    echo $data->og_object->likes->summary->total_count;
}

?>
```

Comment: This does not work for me. I tried your whole code, but it does not echoing enything.

Comment: If you prefer put the result of the URL into a variable $json and just do this bit:

Comment: $json_output = json_decode($json);
foreach( $json_output as $site=>$data ){
    echo $site."\n";
    echo $data->og_object->likes->summary->total_count;
}

Comment: unfortunatelly this still doesn't help me... If I just var_dumb $json_output, it doesn't return me enything.

Comment: I resolved the problem... I needed to add an access token at the end of $url

So $url looks like: $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/?fields=og_object%7Blikes.limit(0).summary(true)%7D%2Cshare&ids=http%3A%2F%2Frobinhud.si%2Fdozivetja%2Fkit-preseneti-surferko%2F&access_token=<ACCESS TOKEN>";