# Coverting string variable to array

Tags: php

when run `var_dump($myVariable)` I have this string, this variable is not json :

```
string(13) "['1','2','3']"
```

but I want have this:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "3" }
```

how can I convert $myVariable to second format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling data in a PHP JSON Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263392/handling-data-in-a-php-json-object)

Comment: try json_decode on the string variable

Comment: @Calimero no that not json,that is array created in foreach but when export it, its return string inseted array

Comment: @Shahrukh have you seen any `{}` in my result!!
thats not json

Comment: an you show us what is in your foreach please ?

Comment: kindly show the loop that is creating the array

Comment: It doesn't have to have curly braces to be JSON, but the single quotes do mean that it isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the string you are converting is consistent, the following isn't tested, but you can do something like the following:

```
$string = "['1','2','3']";
$string = str_replace(['[','\'',']'], '', $string);
$array = explode(',', $string);
```